# VBA find last ROW with values without checking each cell

Tags: vba, excel

for my excel VBA project I have the following code that finds my last row that contains any data. It checks each row in my sheet and looks if a value is inserted (bottom up):

```
lRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=Range("A1"), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row
```

This works perfectly but the problem is that if loops over all records, so more than 1.000.000 calculations are done to find my the last row that has a value. I chose for this approach because my data isn't consistent, it consists out of 3 columns that all **can** have some data. To illustrate:

```
| A          | B           | C            |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| This       |        This |     This     
|            |      column |          
|            |             |     will     
| be         |          be |      be      
| left       |             |         
|            |             |   aligned
```

The only assurance I have is that at least one of the 3 columns is filled with data. Is it possible to write a function in VBA that starts from the top and checks if A or B or C is filled, if it isn't, the previous row should be returned? (Without a lot of code?)

Comment: Why do you think your current code loops over all records? Have you done some timings that suggest this code is slow? You have `After:=Range("A1")` and `SearchDirection:=xlPrevious` and `SearchOrder:=xlByRows`. This means the search for a value starts in the bottom right corner of the worksheet and moves up row by row until it finds a value. We are told that Excel uses sparse storage so no space is taken for rows that do not contain anything. The search for the last row with a value should be near instantaneous.

Comment: The code posted in the question sets `lrow` to the last row with any data although there could be rows above `lrow` which are empty.  You tell us this works perfectly.  You seem to think this code is slow because it loops over all records and involves a 1,000,000 calculations but offer no explanation as to why you think this which does not match my understanding of how `Find` works.  Your final sentence is unclear to me.  One reading is that above the last row there might be rows with all three columns blank.  If so, you want the row above the first such row.

Comment: With my test data, the first answer gives the same result as yours but takes about 13 times longer.  The second answer also gives the same result but take 20 minutes.  The third answer finds the first blank row from the top.  If that blank row is near row 1, it is quick.  If that blank row is near row 1,000,000, it takes 7 seconds.  If your original code gives the correct answer, I have a variation that is 4 times faster.  Does your original code give the correct answer or not?

Comment: @Alfons Ingomar did you try the code in my answer below, let me know if it works as you intended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this, find last row per column and compare if it's the **LastRow** with highest value.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindLastRow()

Dim col As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim MaxLastRow As Long

MaxLastRow = 2 ' initialize value

' modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' loop from column A to Column C >> can modify easily
    For col = 1 To 3
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
        If MaxLastRow < LastRow Then MaxLastRow = LastRow
    Next col
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**edited** to handle non contiguous ranges

you can try this function:

```
Function RangeLastRow(rng As Range) As Long
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
        With Intersect(rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow, rng).EntireRow
            RangeLastRow = Split(.Areas(.Areas.Count).Address, "$")(2)
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

which will return:

- zero, if passed range has empty cells only
- row index of not empty "farthest" cell, if passed range has at least one not empty cell

Comment: did it work for you ? I tested it (because I realy liked this elegant and short code) but it return `0` for me

Comment: @ShaiRado, I tested with some columns selections passed to a `MsgBox RangeLastRow(Selection)` statement. What test doesn't work for you?

Comment: I have a `Sub Test` , with `Dim lastr As Long` and `lastr = RangeLastRow(Range("A:A"))` , and I am not getting the correct value for `lastr`. what am I not doing right ?

Comment: also when trying to use `lastr = RangeLastRow(Columns("A:C"))` , I am not getting the desired result

Comment: I guess you have cells with formulas, haven't you?

Comment: Yes, empty cells could result in non contiguous ranges from `SpecialCells` that would require special handling. See edited code: three more rows (grrr...)

Comment: you should actualy thank me for debugging and improving your code :) , its sweet though ++1

Comment: Of course; I thank you! Sorry for forgetting that. My debug was actually limited to OP's data, but it's been a good thing to make the solution wider. There are still some limit cases missing, but may be of as little interest as easy to enhance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as though you already have some answers that work. I'll throw my hat in the ring just for the sake of variety.

```
Sub test()
Dim Count As Long
Dim A As String
Dim B As String
Dim C As String
With Sheets("Sheet1")
Range("D1").Select
For Count = 1 To 1000000
A = .Cells(Count, "A")
B = .Cells(Count, "B")
C = .Cells(Count, "C")

combined = A & B & C
.Cells(Count, "D").Value = combined
DoEvents
If combined = "" Then GoTo Line100
Next
End With

Line100:

End Sub
```

This macro stops at the last row that does not have any values in column A, B, or C.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from John Walkenbach's book 'Excel 2007 Power Programming with VBA' try:

```
Nextrow = cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlup).row +1
```